# Bulk Edit Published Post with variable in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, regex, wordpress

I have a wordpress site, it's already have about about 3000 published posts, the problem is i want to do a customization to the published post automatically.

For example, i have a published post:

> title: "ABC LCD Monitor"
>     content: "ABC LCD Monitor is a very popular product, bla bla bla."

And i want to edit to

> title: "ABC LCD Monitor"
>     content:
> "Welcome to the [title] page."
>   "This is the review about [title]:"
>   "[original post]"
>   "Buy it now!"

You can see the [title] is replaced by the post title, and the [original post] is replaced by the previous content of the post:

> "ABC LCD Monitor is a very popular
>   product, bla bla bla."

Is this possible to do and how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to run sql cmd in mysql database:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = concat('Welcome to the ',post_title, ' page.This is the review about ',post_title, ':<br />', post_content,'<br />Buy it now！')
```